# Geb: Access content of head element

Tags: testing, webdriver, geb

I am trying to add *at checker* to page, which check content of head element.

**HTML:**

```
<meta name="app.environment" content="beta">
```

**How can I access text of content atribute in Geb test** (I would like to use *At checkers* on particular page)

Answer (score 0):

`$('meta[name="app.environment"]').attr('content')` or if you like your code concise then it can be also done using `$(name: 'app.environment').@content`. There is a [section in the manual about accessing attributes](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#accessing-tag-name-attributes-text-and-classes).